# Rspec - expected ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid but nothing was raised?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I'm creating tests using rspec and trying to raise an error "ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid", but I keep getting "expected ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid but nothing was raised"

I'm pretty new to rspec testing and this is actually my first time directly asking a question on stack overflow. Thus my question might be juvenile, so I do apologize in advance.

```
class InsiderMailAddress < ActiveRecord::Base

   def self.get_list_by_role(role)
   address = InsiderMailAddress.find_by_role(role)
   end
end


 describe "get list by role" do    
   it "raises error when invalid role is given" do
     expect {
     InsiderMailAddress.get_list_by_role(:role)
   }.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats the wrong exception.

`ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` is raised when a record is invalid. Pretty self explanatory.

```
class Country < ApplicationRecord
  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

---

```
irb(main):001:0> Country.create
   (0.7ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
=> #<Country id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):002:0> Country.create!
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Name can't be blank
    from (irb):2
```

As you can see it is not raised when you call [`.create`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-create) - but it is when you call  the "bang" methods [`.save!`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save-21) and [`.create!`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-create-21).

What you may be looking for is `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`.

```
irb(main):001:0> Country.find(1)
  Country Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "countries".* FROM "countries" WHERE "countries"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Country with 'id'=1
    from (irb):1
irb(main):002:0> Country.find_by(id: 1)
  Country Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "countries".* FROM "countries" WHERE "countries"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> Country.find_by!(id: 1)
  Country Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "countries".* FROM "countries" WHERE "countries"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Country
    from (irb):3
```

As you can see from this example it is not raised by [`.find_by`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by) - rather it just returns nil. If you want to raise an exception then you need to use `.find_by!` instead. The same applies to [dynamic finders](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#dynamic-finders).

Comment: I don't have a good answer to why the `.find` method is not `.find!` for consistency.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

you should use `find_by!` to raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception.

Only validations raise `ActiveRecord::InvalidRecord`, not `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`